# Manage customers giving error in Magento Admin Panel

Tags: php, magento

[image: error in image]My Magento Admin panel giving following error while I try to create new customer from admin panel.

> "Associate to Website" is a required value.
>
> "Group" is a required value.
>
> "First Name" is a required value.
>
> "First Name" length must be equal or greater than 1 characters.
>
> "Last Name" is a required value.
>
> "Last Name" length must be equal or greater than 1 characters.
>
> "Email" is a required value.

No matter how hard I am trying I am not getting rid of this error.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: send me ur login and let me see

Comment: sorry sir, i can't as it is live site.but i can attach a snapshot

Comment: ok attach the snapshot

Comment: i cant as stack overflow is not allowing me. i need atleast 10 reputation to attach a snapshot. can i have ur email id

Comment: @santoshbawari - Attach snapshot now , you have 11 reputation..

Comment: i have attached a snapshot . kindly look into it. i have my hands up

Comment: Do you work on multi-shop concept?

Comment: i do , but this not multi-shop case. this is single store site